# The Text is getting cleared in MudBlazor Autocomplete component

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am working on the Blazor web assembly project which is running on .net7 and using MudBlazor (version-6.0.10) as the UI framework. so I have created a custom autocomplete component in MudBlazor.
then my issue is the text that I type on this autocomplete is getting cleared automatically while searching/typing
following you can see that razor component.

```
<MudAutocomplete T="ItemResponse"
                     Label="AutoComplete" 
                     SearchFunc="@OnComboSearch"  
                     Value="selecteditemResponse"
                     ValueChanged="OnComboValueChanged"
                     ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" DebounceInterval="700"/>
```

```
@code{

    private ItemResponse selecteditemResponse = new ItemResponse();
    IList<ItemResponse> ItemRes = new List<ItemResponse>();
    private bool IsServerFiltering =true;
  
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {   
        await ReadAutoCompleteData();
       
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


   protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync(){}


   private async Task<IEnumerable<ItemResponse>> OnComboSearch(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            selecteditemResponse = new ItemResponse();
            return ItemRes;
        }
        
        if (IsServerFiltering)
        {
            await ReadAutoCompleteData(value);
        }
        return ItemRes.Where(x => x.ItemName!=null && x.ItemName.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }


    public async Task ReadAutoCompleteData(string SearchQuery="")
    {
        ComboRequestDTO requestDTO = new ComboRequestDTO();
        requestDTO.SearchQuery = SearchQuery;
   
        ItemRes = await _comboManager.GetItemResponses(requestDTO);//api call

        /*here i am getting the data for this autocomplete through an api call and assign it to a
          ItemRes list
        (normally we are getting more than 3000 items for this combo if SearchQuery string is null
        or empty 
        otherwise only 10 records are coming)*/
    }

    private async Task OnComboValueChanged(ItemResponse itemResponse)
    {
       if (itemResponse != null)
        {
            await NotifyHooks(itemResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            await NotifyHooks(new ItemResponse());
        }
    }
    private async Task<ItemResponse> NotifyHooks(ItemResponse ItemResponse)
    {
        try
        {
                selecteditemResponse = ItemResponse;
                StateHasChanged();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return ItemResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you already work through the examples showcased at https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#usage? Your example is confusing as it does not really match the examples and from my point of view there are some questionable parts like `@bind-value` is not used.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. You will need to provide a [try.mudblazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet) snippet with enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: MaxItems property?  defaults to 10. A null value will display all items.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ValueChanged` EventCallback in `MudAutoComplete` instead of `@bind-Value` you must implement the logic to change the `Value` in the method you set to handle `ValueChanged`.

```
private async Task OnComboValueChanged(ItemResponse itemResponse)
{
    // 
    selecteditemResponse = itemResponse;
}
```

[tryMudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcHYIFtiOmNQxKr)

Comment: yeah, I am doing the thing that you have proposed right here.i will update my problem

Comment: I have edited my question, please look into that ,thanks